# Can not bind textblock property from another class to UI class using MVVM

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I'm a beginner of sliverlight and MVVM.
I can not bind textblock property from another class to UI class using MVVM.

My code is here.
Please let me know how to bind textblock property in bellow Authentication.cs.

MainPage.xaml

```
<TextBlock Height="30" Margin="122,218,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="{Binding Path=ErrorStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="86" />
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private Authentication authentication;

// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = authentication;
}
```

ViewModelBase.cs

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Authentication.cs

```
public class Authentication : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _ErrorStatus;
    public string ErrorStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _ErrorStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _ErrorStatus = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ErrorStatus");
        }
    }

    void Authenticate()
    {
        //Here, I write authentication code....
        //After the authentication code, I want to change textBlock property depend on auth status.
        //Please let me know how to write code.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write `ErrorStatus = "Access Denied";` in your `Authenitcate()` method

The TextBox's Text is pointing to the `ErrorStatus` property, so anytime it updates the TextBox will also get updated automatically.

The only thing you need to be sure of is that you call `Authenticate()` on the same object that the TextBox is bound to.

```
private Authentication authentication = new Authentication();

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // New line here
    this.authentication = new Authentication();

    this.DataContext = authentication;
}

void btnAuthenticate_Click(object src, EventArgs e)
{
    authentication.Authenticate();
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ErrorStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created a new instance of `Authentication`. Add the following line to the main window constuctor:

```
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // New line here
    this.authentication = new Authentication();

    this.DataContext = authentication;
}
```

When you call `Authenticate()`, you can just assign a new value to `ErrorStatus` and it should show up in the `TextBlock`.

Comment: I call Authentication() instance in Button(button1_click) in MainPage.xaml. 
So, I couldn't change property if I added this.authentication = new Authentication();.

    void Authenticate()
    {
        //Here, I write authentication code....
        //After the authentication code, I want to change textBlock property depend on auth status.
        //Please let me know how to write code.
        
        //I added bellow code. but I couldn't change property.
        ErrorStatus = "Access Denied."
    }

Comment: Why not? Once the DataContext is set properly (in the constructor, prior to the button click code,) updating the viewmodel will cause the binding to push the value to the `TextBlock`.

Comment: @okame You want to add that line in the constructor, not in Authenticate. Once the line is added in the constructor, you won't need to make any changes to Authenticate (other than assigning a new value to ErrorStatus)

Comment: Thanks reply. I want to assigning a new value to ErroStatus in Authentication class. So I added the code ErrorStatus = "Access Denied."; in Authenticate(). But ErrorStatus didn't change when debugger went through the code. Please let me know how to change ErrorStatus in Authenticate().

Answer (score 0):

This is where the delegate command pattern (also called relay command) comes into play http://kharasoft.wordpress.com/2007/10/16/the-delegating-command/ using this pattern, instead of handling button click in your code behind, your viewmodel exposes an instance of ICommand that does little more than routing the events to a method on the viewmodel. Now authenticate runs in the context of your viewmodel and can update the property directly.

Comment: Laurent Bugnion provides an implementation of delegate command in his mvvmlight library that works in silverlight