# Can not bind textblock property from another class to UI class using MVVM.(vol. 2)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I asked can not bind textblock property from another class to UI class using MVVM in the previous post.
[Can not bind textblock property from another class to UI class using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721947/can-not-bind-textblock-property-from-another-class-to-ui-class-using-mvvm)

I can not still bind textblock property, but I found a new thing that PropertyChanged event becomes null when I cannot bind textblock property.

Please see bellow code (also see the previous post) :

```
public class Authentication : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _ErrorStatus;
    public string ErrorStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _ErrorStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _ErrorStatus = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ErrorStatus");
        }
    }

    void Authenticate()
    {
        //The bellow code doesn't work.
        ErrorStatus = "Access Denied.";
    }
}
```

In the bellow code, PropertyChanged becomes null.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        //PropertyChanged is null, so event is not called and ErrorStatus is not changed.
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to write correct code and why PropertyChanged becomes null.

I already confirmed that ErrorStatus changes correctly when ErrorStatus is called in UI class (MainPage.cs).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your problem or not, but:

the way you are firing event is not thread-safe. Not only here but always fire your events like this:

```
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```