# How to divide properties class and methods class in MVVM

Tags: windows-phone-7

Last time, I submitted a question about using property in MVVM in my Windows Phone 7 app.
I could well done by excellent advices. Please see my previous question.

[Can not bind textblock property from another class to UI class using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721947/can-not-bind-textblock-property-from-another-class-to-ui-class-using-mvvm)

Through my coding, MVVM properties are increasing. So I want to divide properties class and methods.
But I couldn't divide it. Please let me know how to divide properties class and methods class in MVVM.

My code is here.

Authentication.cs

```
public class Authentication : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _ErrorStatus;
    public string ErrorStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _ErrorStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _ErrorStatus = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ErrorStatus");
        }
    }

    void Authenticate()
    {
        ErrorStatus = "Access Denied";
    }
}
```

I want to divide like this. But "ErrorStatus" is not changed.

Properties.cs

```
public class Properties : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _ErrorStatus;
    public string ErrorStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _ErrorStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _ErrorStatus = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ErrorStatus");
        }
    }
}
```

Authentication.cs

```
public class Authentication
{
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    void Authenticate()
    {
        //not work
        properties.ErrorStatus = "Access Denied";
    }
}
```

Comment: May I recommend you start using http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/ , to avoid the heavy amount of boilerplate you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following enables `Authentication` to have access to properties of `Properties` and shows how it could work.

```
public class Properties : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _ErrorStatus;
    public string ErrorStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _ErrorStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            _ErrorStatus = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ErrorStatus");
        }
    }
}

public class Authentication : Properties
{
    public void Authenticate()
    {
        ErrorStatus = "Access Denied";
    }
}

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var test = new Authentication();

        test.Authenticate();

        MessageBox.Show(test.ErrorStatus); // Displays "Access Denied"
    }
}
```

Comment: @okame I've updated the answer to show how this does work. If this isn't what you're trying to achieve can you please update the question to clarify

Comment: It's cool!! I could resolve my question by your solution. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the same old

```
private Authentication authentication;  
public MainPage() 
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.authentication = new Authentication();
     this.DataContext = authentication; 
}  
void btnAuthenticate_Click(object src, EventArgs e) 
{
     authentication.Authenticate(); 
}
```

and

```
public class Authentication
{
    private string properties = new Properties();
    public string Properties
    {
        get
        {
            return properties;
        }
        set
        {
            properties = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Properties");
        }
    }
    void Authenticate()
    {
        Properties.ErrorStatus = "Access Denied";
    }
}
```

the normal xaml should then be

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Properties.ErrorStatus}" />
```

but sometimes, you change the Properties instance.
so if it don't work, you can try this xaml

```
<Border DataContext="{Binding Properties}">
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ErrorStatus}" /> 
</Border>
```